# My Progressive Web App's colored splash screen isn't working

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I followed the steps included [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-web-app-manifest-to-set-solid-color-loading-screen) to add color to my site's splash screen when being opened from the Home Screen. However, for some reason it still shows as white right now instead of the blue color I set. I verified that I'm running the latest chrome version (v56) on Android (7.1), but I'm still getting a white screen. Anyone have any idea what could be going on?

This is my website;

https://sgarcia-dev.github.io

This is my `manifest.json` file's contents;

```
{
    "name": "Sergei Garcia - Front End Developer",
    "description": "Web Developer, Aspiring Designer, Tech Enthusiast & Blogger.",
    "short_name": "Sergei's Profile",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "dist/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png",
            "sizes": "120x120",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "background_color": "#2B3A42",
    "theme_color": "#FF530D",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

And here is the full code repository of my website;

https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/sgarcia-dev.github.io

Comment: Works for me. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: I would guess your browser had the manifest cached and was not fetching the version with a color specified.